# Creating an Excel formula to return a specific non-blank mapped value from another row

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am working with a large mapping table in excel. The output of the mapping table is difficult to use when performing analysis and for creating custom files for users.

The Data table is formatted as such:
[image: Link to Data Table Image]

I would like the New Account Lookup column to always return the mapped system account, as some of the mapped system account output rows from the mapping table are blank due to the system design. The location of the new system account data can be varied in terms of the row number.

Have tried index match and a few complicated if statement variants to no avail. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please show us your efforts and how they didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to figure this out using the following as an array formula: INDEX(C:C,MATCH(1,(A1=A:A)*(C:C<>""),0))